# A rotating list: what is it called?

Tags: word-request

You have a list of people; let's say ten. There is a task that should be done by all but in pairs or even threes, and once all have done their task, then cycle repeats from the beginning.

The question is what is this list called?

Comment: Oddly enough, it is often call a "rotation", a "rotating schedule", or a "rotating shift"! See [**this search.**](https://www.google.com/search?q=schedule+rotation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Agreed, +1 for "rotation".

Comment: In British English I would call it a "rota".

Answer (score 2):

*Rotation* is appropriate, but consider using the term *round robin.*